# How to restore deleted files in Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, phone, trash

I'm looking for a recycle bin location and/or ways to recover deleted files using the file manager on an Ubuntu Touch phone.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, if you delete files using File manager or on the Desktop by highlighting a file and hitting Delete, or you right click on a file and select 'Move to Trash' (or 'Move to Rubbish Bin', if, like me, you live in the UK) then the file goes in $HOME/.local/share/Trash.

However, there is no such file on an Ubuntu Phone, so you cannot recover deleted files.

Whenever you delete something the confirmation message will tell you that you are about to **permanently** delete the file.

Comment: I´m looking in /home/phablet/.local/share but there is not /Trash folder at all :-(

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no /Trash folder on an Ubuntu phone.